# jQuery and postMessage on iframe

Tags: jquery

I have the following links that load into the iframe called contentFrame.

```
<a href="/url/to/link1" target="contentFrame">LINK 1</a> | <a href="/url/to/link2" target="contentFrame">LINK 2</a>

<iframe src="url/path" name="contentFrame" id="contentFrame" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I then have the following jQuery onclick function to load the link in the link into the iframe.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#contentFrame").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    })
});
<script>
```

However, I need to add a postMessage in the following format when I load the links.

```
{action:'navigate', route: { path: 'url/path'}}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can incorporate this postMessage into my existing code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can use iframe load event and get iframe window context inside it and post to that window

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('#contentFrame').on('load', function() {
      this.contentWindow.postMessage({
        action: 'navigate',
        route: {
          path: 'url/path'
        }
      })
    });
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4udGSGiBiIs3goGwHb9m?p=preview)**</kbd>